# view port edge deformation glitch in 2.9

Tags: 3d-view, edges

just downloaded the 2.9 and started doing some stuff but i noticed that some wiggly zig zag glitch is happening with the viewport , all the meshes in the viewport are getting glitched in the edges , here see some pics

[image]

no such problem in wireframe
[image]

Comment: That's not from the mesh intersection? Can I see the wireframe?

Comment: Reduce the view clip distance. This is a floating point rounding error because your view clip range is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduced the view clip distance. This is a floating point rounding error because your view clip range is too broad - @Gorgious